# In a European country, it is possible to withdraw money, for example, from an e-wallet or electronic payment system, without using a bank account?

Tags: banking, paypal, payment

Is there a way in Latvia to withdraw money from an e-wallet (such as Qiwi and ....) or an electronic payment system (such as PayPal, Skrill and ....) without using a bank account. Maybe some payment system has its own card or something like that?

Comment: Withdraw it to *where*?

Comment: You can certainly transfer PayPal funds to another user, if they accept payment that way. But eventually someone is going to want money that can be used outside of PayPal, and that means someone will have to go through a bank.

Comment: I assume Diana is thinking of retrieving cash? (Isn't that a bit uncommon in Latvia?)

Answer (score 1):

PayPal is regulated as a bank in the EU (see [here](https://www.paypal.com/ie/webapps/mpp/about)):

> PayPal (Europe) S.à r.l. et Cie, S.C.A. is a credit institution (or bank) authorised and supervised by the Commission de Surveillance du Secteur Financier (or CSSF) in Luxembourg and is regulated by the Central Bank of Ireland for conduct of business rules.

So you cannot withdraw from PayPal without going through a bank because PayPal *is* a bank.

Skrill is not technically a bank. [Their ToS](https://strefawalut.pl/static/regulamin/scrill.com-pobrany-2016-08-26.pdf) allows withdrawals in several manner, however it appears that they do have to involve banks:

> Withdrawal methods are payment services provided, **at least in part**, by
> third party financial institutions (for example, the bank where you hold a
> bank account).

Answer (score 0):

Both Skrill and PayPal explicitely offer cards. PayPal does explicitely advertise that you do not need a traditional bank account to use it. Yet they both only seen to offer this for business accounts.